# 'UnboundLocalError' in same function to download attachment from Outlook 2013 when run with different parameters

Tags: python, outlook, email-attachments, win32com

I am trying to download attachments from outlook 2013 on windows 7. I wrote following function for it:

```
def attach(subject,name):
    print "Execution begin"  
    outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder("6")
    all_inbox = inbox.Items
    val_date = date.date.today()

    print "accessing parameters"
    sub_today = subject
    att_today = name

    for msg in all_inbox:
        if msg.Subject == sub_today:
        print "sub_today"
        break
    for attachment in msg.Attachments:
        if attachment.FileName == att_today:
        print "att_today"
        print attachment
        break

    repository='C:\\Users\\tanmay.shrivastava\\Desktop\\Dashboard'
    print "repository"
    attachment.SaveAsFile(repository + '\\'+att_today)
    print "saved"
    print "Execution completed"
```

I called the function with two different lists: list 1 and list 2.

```
list1=['Hi','cr.txt']
list2=['abc Requirements','cr.txt']
```

The code is working when I call it with list1.

```
attach(list1[0],list1[1])
```

but when I call it with parameters from list2, it shows error

```
attach(list2[0],list2[1])

UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-4238cd3c2efd> in <module>()
----> 1 attach(list2[0],list2[1])

<ipython-input-2-3bb862eb2bb6> in attach(subject, name)
     26     repository='C:\\Users\\tanmay.shrivastava\\Desktop\\Dashboard'
     27     print "repository"
---> 28     attachment.SaveAsFile(repository + '\\'+att_today)
     29     print "saved"
     30     print "Execution completed"

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'attachment' referenced before assignment
```

I don't know what is causing it. Can someone help me with it?

Comment: My guess is `msg.Attachments` was empty therefore `attachment` was never defined.

Comment: @AlexFung I tested it by sending an email to myself with required attachment. If the mail is not present then i guess it raises an "AttributeError"

Comment: So my solution doesn't avoid the errors?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have the error is that there is no msg or attachment found.

This would not raise the error as mentioned in the question:

```
def attach(subject,name):
    print "Execution begin"  
    outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder("6")
    all_inbox = inbox.Items
    val_date = date.date.today()

    print "accessing parameters"

    for msg in all_inbox:
        if msg.Subject == subject:
            print "sub_today"

            for attachment in msg.Attachments:
                if attachment.FileName == name:
                    print "att_today"
                    print attachment

                    repository='C:\\Users\\tanmay.shrivastava\\Desktop\\Dashboard'
                    print "repository"
                    attachment.SaveAsFile(repository + '\\'+name)
                    print "saved"
                    print "Execution completed"
                    return True
```

Comment: I emailed myself the required file with the required mail-subject, but it was causing the error. I will check whether this works or not.

Comment: Let me know how it goes.

Comment: it is still showing the `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'attachment' referenced before assignment`

Comment: That is impossible for my code to raise this error as `attachment` is only used in the `for attachment in msg.Attachments:` . You sure you replaced your code with mine??

Comment: yes @AlexFung I replaced my code with yours, but i'll create a separate file and check it again, to avoid the possibility of interence